# Ubuntu 18.04 Connect to Xserver from remote

Tags: connection, remote, xserver

I have setup an Ubuntu 18.04 on a Touchscreen-Display and I want to start 
a graphical programm from a remote system to display it on the touchscreen.

When I try it I get the error

> Can't open display

I've removed the option '-nolisten tcp' from starting the X-Server, but that is not the whole solution. `netstat` doesn't show that port 6000 is open for listening and I think thats the Problem.

I use the Displaymanager slim with Windowmanager mwm.
I say thank you to any Idea you have.

Answer (score 1):

If connected via SSH, try adding `DISPLAY=:0` first, before desired command.
`DISPLAY=:0 command-to-run`
It should open a program on first display in Ubuntu.

Comment: The Problem is, that I not want to connect to the Touchscreen-Computer. I just want to redirect the graphical Output to the Touchscreen-Computer. (e.g.: > setenv DISPLAY <IP-Adresse>:0.0;xterm)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution.
I start the X-Server with the Option '-listen tcp' and then it works.
In the file /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc I finally change the Option from
'-nolisten tcp' to '-listen tcp'